# how to write an expression in SSRS to filter data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression

I need to filter my result based on Parameter value. If it says `"Open"` then `DueDate` column should be `= NULL,` if says `'Closed'` that `DueDate = NOT NULL`, and if it says `"Both"` then it should grab all `DueDate`s

I have created query parameter "Status" that gives me 3 possible values:

[image]

Next I created report parameter `"Status"` and `Allow Multiple Values`

[image]

Now I go to my main query and go to Filters:

[image]

And here I cant understand how can I write an expression saying:

If report "status" value = "Open" then show me the result  where DueDate IS NULL,
If report "Status" value = "Closed" then DueDate IS NOT NULL ,
And If report "Status" value = "Both" then show me all DueDates ( null and not null)

Another thing is I already have case statement in my query:

```
ALTER Procedure
AS
@ShowOpen bit = 0,
@ShowClosed bit = 0
 SELECT
 FROM 
 WHERE 
              AND
                        (
                        (CASE WHEN (@ShowOpen = 1) THEN
                              CASE WHEN (tblNoteRecipients.CompletedDate IS NULL and tblNoteRecipients.IsDiary = 1) or tblNoteRecipients.UserGUID is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                             -- CASE WHEN (tblNoteRecipients.CompletedDate IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                        ELSE
                              1
                        END = 1)
                  AND
                        (CASE WHEN (@ShowClosed = 1) THEN
                              CASE WHEN (tblNoteRecipients.CompletedDate IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                        ELSE
                              1
                        END = 1)
                  OR    ((@ShowOpen = 1) AND (@ShowClosed = 1))
                        )
```

Is any way out of it in SSRS I can create parameter that accepts values Open, Closed and Both?

Added test1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Filter in the tablix like this:

[image]

In `Expression` use:

```
=IIF(
(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Status.Value,"Open")>-1 and 
Isnothing(Fields!DueDate.Value)) or
(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Status.Value,"Closed")>-1 and not 
Isnothing(Fields!DueDate.Value)) or
(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Status.Value,"Both")>-1),
 "Include","Exclude")
```

For `Value` use:

```
="Include"
```

Comment: Unfortunately It says "Failed to evaluate the filtervalues for MyDataSet".
I have modified my post, and added the code, that already in my stored procedure (I am not the author of it) but can I use that case statement in my SSRS report? In order to make not boolean filters, but  "Open","Closed" and "Both"?

Comment: @Oleg, It works just fine for me. Are you sure you are using the exact same expression and `=` for `Operator` setting in the Filter.

Comment: I have added a snip.

Comment: Not sure what are you doing, but would love to learn this way

Comment: @Oleg, are you passing the parameter to the SP? that would not be necessary if you are performing the filtering in SSRS. Just remove the **where** clause in your SP and try again.